# Proving recursion depth of merge sort

Tags: time-complexity, master-theorem

Hello I want to prove the recursion depth of merge sort, which is $O(\log(n))$.
I think I can prove this by recurrence equation and the master theorem: 
$T(N)=2 T(n/2)+O(N) $ however i need to get $O(\log(n)) $. Basically I want only to calculate the complexity of the deviding and remove the conquer part from this equation. How can I do this? Or is there another way to prove the height of the recursion tree?

In the picture below you can see I want to prove the height from red to gray.

[image]

Comment: refer to recrusion tree method of solving recurrences.

Comment: You can use the master theorem to prove the (worst-case) *time complexity* of mergesort. That does not give you a direct proof of the *height* of the comparison tree.

Comment: solved with recrusion tree method thanks @NavjotWaraich

Comment: @raviolican Consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It might be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me correct the recursion for the running time of merge sort:
$$
T(n) = \begin{cases} T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + \Theta(n) & \text{if } n > 1, \\ \Theta(1) & \text{if } n = 1. \end{cases}
$$
The corresponding recursion for depth is:
$$
D(n) = \begin{cases} \max(D(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor), D(\lceil n/2 \rceil)) + 1 & \text{if } n > 1, \\ 0 & \text{if } n = 1. \end{cases}
$$
(The value of $D(1)$ could also be $1$, depending on how you define depth.)

The solution of this recurrence is $D(n) =\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$.

When $n$ is a power of 2, you can calculate the depth of the recursion tree by noticing that the value of $n$ decreases by a factor of 2 at each level. For the general case, the main observation is that the depth is monotone in $n$, using which you can easily conclude $D(n) \leq \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ by considering the smallest power of 2 which is at least $n$.